# php mysql echoing count on screen

Tags: php, mysql

My blog has a sidebar which needs to display archives. The formatting is as such that the name of month should be followed by the number of blog posts published in that particular month, for example, March(17), where there are 17 posts in the month of march. 
Here is my php code:

```
      $y = date("Y");
      $m = date("m");

      $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","yomadsdata");
      $sql = 'select count(*) from blogposts where post_created like "$y_$m_%"';
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      // Code to be inserted.

      $conn->close();
```

Its is incomplete, I need to know the phpmysql  code that needs to be inserted so as to get the desired output.

Comment: In which format is your date saved in the database?

Comment: timestamp, YYYY-mm-dd h:m:s

Comment: remove `_` and use `-`

Comment: please show the complete code.

Comment: better use prepared statements combined with `post_created BETWEEN ..`

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem? Does the `SELECT` return the proper rows?

Comment: the sql statement works fine and returns the count. I just want to display it in html document.

Comment: So you do not need count(*)

Comment: I need the count to show the number of posts in a particular month. Like this:
March(9)
April (14) and so on.

Comment: Use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) example.. Good luck

Comment: If you need count, use next one query for display the data

Comment: So where is your html ?

Comment: do you want particular month only or all months count

Comment: select count(*) as count  from blogposts GROUP BY YEAR(post_created), MONTH(post_created)